# Proving that if two line segments are equal iff another pair of angles are equal.

Tags: contest-math, circles, triangles

**Question:**

> Suppose that $P$ and $Q$ are points on the sides $AB$ and $AC$ respectively of $\triangle ABC.$ The perpendiculars to the sides $AB$ and $AC$ at $P$ and $Q$ respectively meet at $D,$ an interior point of $\triangle ABC$. If $M$ is the midpoint of $BC,$ prove that $PM=QM$ if and only if $\angle BDP=\angle CDQ$.

**My Problem:** This question is to be proved by taking one of the two given things as correct and other as false and contradict both statements.
There are certain things which I think are correct for the problem but I can't prove that.
$1.$ $PQCB$ is cyclic quadrilateral.
$2.$ $M$ is center of the circle$(PQCB)$.
$3.$ $P,D,C$ and $Q,D,B$ are collinear.
  I found that $\triangle PDB \sim \triangle QDC$ which gives $QD*DB=PD*DC$. This is my only progress.

Thanks for providing a solution.

Comment: I am a bit confused as to the actual conditions on the setup. What is it in the setup that forces the circle centered at $M$ through $P,Q$ to also pass through $B,C$? Did you accidentally leave out a condition?

Comment: See that if you take both things to be correct, you'll end up at all those conclusions.

Comment: OK, I actually do not think that it follows that $PQCB$ is cyclic. Clearly $\Delta PDB\sim\Delta QDC$ though, since both triangles have a right angle so if another angle is shared, they are forced to be similar.

Comment: 1,2,3 aren't conclusions but just intuitions which are correct for the problem. For example you know that there are infinites of primes but its proof isn't as trivial.

Comment: Yes, I know. But I suspect those intuitions are misleading. Draw any circle centered at $M$ not passing through $B,C$, but intersecting $AB,AC$ at points that you name $P,Q$ and you can finish the figure to have a setup not fulfilling any of the three, yet fulfilling the conditions of the problem.

Comment: @String- See M lies on perpendicular bisector of PQ and is midpoint of BC alone tells you everything. You have 2 statements, 1 proves that it lies on perpendicular bisector and second one defines the point more clearly.

Comment: See the situation given in my answer - it satisfies the conditions (though I left out $A$ for clarity), but it does not conform to the conditions in your 3-point list of intuitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Let $E$ and $F$ be midpoints of $BD$ and $CD$ respectively. Then $MFDE$ is parallelogram and $PE= BD/2= MF$ and $F = CD/2 = EM$. Now $$PM = PQ\iff \angle PEM = \angle MFQ \iff \angle PED = \angle DFQ \iff ...$$

Comment: How $PE=CD/2$??

Comment: Triangle $PCD$ is right at $P$ and PE is median on hypothenus

Comment: I think you mean $PE=BD/2$ and then the next part is meant to say $QF=DF=CD/2=EM$, if I am not mistaken. Very clever solution!

Comment: @ChristianF-Got it. It was written as $PE=CD/2$

Comment: @ChristianF You are too clever. Are you a professor or famous problem solver?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Here is a proof of the proposition using vectors:

> 1. $PM=QM$ translates to $\renewcommand{\vec}{\overrightarrow}|\vec v-\vec m|=|\vec m+\vec w|$.
> 2. The vector pointing from $P$ to $D$ must be in the direction of $\vec v$ rotated $90^\circ$ clockwise, so it can be written as $-\widehat{\vec v}\cdot p$ for some real number $p$.
> 3. Similarly, the vector from $Q$ to $D$ can be written as $\widehat{\vec w}\cdot q$ for some $q$.
> 4. Now $\Delta BPD$ and $\Delta CQD$ are similar triangles if and only if $p=q$. And this in turn is equivalent to $\angle BDP=\angle CDQ$.

---

Combining 2-4 from above we can write:
$$
\vec{BD}=\vec v-\widehat{\vec v}\cdot p=2\vec m+\vec w+\widehat{\vec w}\cdot p
$$
which can be rearranged to
$$
\vec v-2\vec m-\vec w=(\widehat{\vec v}+\widehat{\vec w})\cdot p
$$
showing that $\vec v-2\vec m-\vec w$ is parallel to $\widehat{\vec v}+\widehat{\vec w}$. Hence it is perpendicular to $\vec v+\vec w$ which is equivalent to saying
$$
(\vec v-2\vec m-\vec w)\cdot(\vec v+\vec w)=0\tag1
$$

---

On the other hand, the first item read $PM=QM$ which implied
$$
|\vec v-\vec m|=|\vec m+\vec w|
$$
which after squaring both sides and applying dot product rules gives us
$$
\vec v\cdot\vec v+\vec m\cdot\vec m-2\vec v\cdot\vec m=\vec m\cdot\vec m+\vec w\cdot\vec w+2\vec m\cdot\vec w\tag2
$$

---

Finally, one can check that $(2)$ is equivalent to $(1)$, and we are done:

> $\angle BDP=\angle CDQ$ is equivalent to $(1)$ which is equivalent to $(2)$ which is equivalent to $PM=QM$. Done!

Comment: Vectors don't fascinate me so I'm very weak at it. I just know the theorems and how to use them. Please ,explain me your last statement.

Comment: @LoveInvariants: Sure, do you mean how I arrived at $(2)$ or how it is seen to be equivalent to $(1)$? I am sure there must be a fine purely geometric proof, but vectors just seemed to do most of the work once I tried.

Comment: I know how you arrived at $(1)$ (by dot product rule). Dont know about $(2)$

Comment: @LoveInvariants: The rule for $(2)$ is that $|\vec u|^2=\vec u\cdot\vec u$ combined with the distributive rule for dot products $$\vec a\cdot(\vec b+\vec c)=\vec a\cdot\vec b+\vec a\cdot\vec c$$ so that e.g. the left hand side can be expanded as a square bracket $$\begin{align}|\vec v-\vec m|^2&=(\vec v-\vec m)\cdot(\vec v-\vec m)\\&=\vec v\cdot\vec v+\vec m\cdot\vec m-2\vec v\cdot\vec m\end{align}$$

Comment: Oh, didn't see both (1) and (2) are same equation. Nice solution. Thanks

Comment: Thank you. If nothing else, my solution has a nice sence of brute force to it since the equations reveal hardly any geometric insight.